# Get a PDF file from a download Link in Dreamfactory with PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, dreamfactory

I am in a situation where I have to upload a PDF file through an API, all of the examples that I have encountered point towards a specified file location, where uploaded through a form or in a specified location on a computer/server.

The issues arises that the PDFs that I have to attach are being provided to me as direct download links. Are there any solutions that would work off of my Virtual Machine setup of Dreamfactory?

Answer (score 0):

So are you trying to POST a PDF  file using DF files service? And are you saying the only way to get the file is via a direct download link? I'm not sure I fully follow what you are trying to achieve but the [DreamFactory scripting](http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Features/Scripting)  may be able to help you implement this.